# swift struct JSON id warning

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I am getting a warning (and I can't dismiss it because it won't run the JSON if I do)

The warning is for the following

```
struct Station: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // WARNING:  Immutable property will not be decoded because it is declared with an initial value which cannot be overwritten
    var name : String
    var imageurl : String
    var listenlive : String

}
```

The problem is the following

I can't make it UUID as I get the following error

`Type 'Station' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

```
// STATION
struct Sdata: Codable {
    var data: [Station]
}

struct Station: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID
    var name : String
    var imageurl : String
    var listenlive : String

}
```

Also technically the let id is wrong because the JSON has it as _id

"_id":"5f52ed668b964609655b48d1"

So How do I make the warning go away while conforming to the correct value type?

Comment: Shouldn't you replace the "=" character with a ":" in your station structure ?

Comment: What does the JSON look like? When `Station` is decoded, do you want `id` to be the value in the JSON, or do you want `id` to be a new UUID created using `UUID()`?

Comment: @Sweeper I want it to be the value of the JSON not create a new value

Comment: The problem is, `5f52ed668b964609655b48d1` is not a valid `UUID`. You have to use a `String` to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it to `id:String` and use `enum CodingKeys` for the custom name `_id`

```
struct Station: Codable , Identifiable  {
  var id,name,imageurl,listenlive:String 

  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case id = "_id", name , imageurl , listenlive 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's not a matter of "getting rid of the warning". What you are doing seems fundamentally wrong.

The way you declared struct Station, every time a new struct is created, its "id" field is set to a new UUID, that is every struct Station has a different id field, that cannot be changed afterwards.

So if we ignore Codeable for the moment, how would you write such a struct to a file and read it back later, getting the same id? Answer: You can't read it back. At some point you create a struct Station with a new, different UUID, and there is no way to store the one that you wrote to a file. So you have a problem here.

So the problem is quite obvious: If you have a "let" property with a non-constant value, Codeable would have to write it, but Decodable cannot read it, so you have a problem. Make "id" a var, possibly with a constructor that sets it to a new UUID, but it *must* be changeable.